# Starting a sentence with "as" intended as a synonym for "Because", "Due to..."

Tags: sentence-construction, as

I've noticed that my group-members (Dutch) start a lot of their written sentences with "As" when they are giving an explanation or a reason.

Example:

> As the library <strike>exists</strike> has existed for several years now, it should be obvious that a lot has changed.

Is this usage of "As" here correct? To me it seems using "Because" or "Due to the fact that ..." would be a lot better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As** is a rather overworked word: check this [freedictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/as) definition. Yes, it can be used in place of "because", but you have to be very careful to avoid confusion in a particular context. In this context, it's fine.

Some people worry about starting a sentence with "because" -[here's why](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/can-you-start-a-sentence-with-because) - but in this case "because" would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

It is fine to use "As" here, and it is fairly common.

> As the library has existed for several years now, it should be obvious that alot has changed.
>
> I am not going to play, as my leg hurts.

Synonyms:

- Because
- Since
- Seeing as
- Considering that

It can also be used to used to indicate that something happens during the time when something else is taking place.

> I turned on the TV as he walked out.

Synonyms:

- While
- Just as
- Seeing as
- Considering that

It can also be used for emphasis.

> As fast as a cheetah.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, **as** is used in place of

> As is the case
>   Because
>   Since
>   Due to the fact

They are all interchangeable, it is a better of style and expression, but using any of the alternatives doesn't change the meaning.